# Is it Possible for Humans to Fly?

Tags: super-powers, supernatural

I was reading a book on Human Super Training. I would like to know if a human body rising into the air is possible. Thank you experts!

Comment: What does your "Human Super Training" book say on the topic?

Comment: The book agrees that human levitation is possible. I don't know how to achieve this and have not understood the level of how possible air movement is in humans, but I would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: Are you asking us to support references in a book that we don't have (and don't even know the title of)?

Comment: I'm not asking you to support this on a book I've read, I'm asking for support on this question about other sources people have found.

Comment: I gave this a try and was able to do it.  But only for about a second.

Comment: Please give a short description about the research you have done. You have an excellent source there to do so. Can you also explain the limitations of your question? Can they use magic? Can they have wings? Can they use technology? etc. Right now, an answer could say the superheroes go through security and check their baggage, and then they take a plane wherever they want to go.

Comment: I'm going to fly this Thursday afternoon...

Comment: Everything is air-droppable at least once

Comment: [According to the World Bank](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/IS.AIR.PSGR), the airlines of this world have carried just a little less than four billion passengers in 2017. I would say that this is definite proof that humans can indeed fly.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Please bear in mind that our goal is to help you develop a fictional world.  We're lenient, but in the future, please try to keep questions focused on that intent.  As for an answer: we do fly, we just use our brains instead of our arms.  (But, from a practical standpoint, and considering your probable intent, the answer is, "no.")

Comment: Only with the aid of a hang glider etc. The human body on its own cannot be made into any shape capable of generating enough lift for sustained fight.

Comment: FWIW, a former GF got into the Transcendal Meditation movement, and they promised her that if she signed up for enough courses. she could learn to "fly" by mental power alone.  I honestly think I spent less on my pilot's license than she did on those courses.

Comment: You are human and have lived with humans all your life. Have you ever seen some dude flying around? Have you ever tried flapping your arms and then started to fly? You use the internet, have you ever seen some indication ever? I think any sane human should be able to figure that one out themselves

Comment: However I've voted to reopen. I fail to see a honest answer yet and I think this is perfectly answerable and the world building potential is obvious enough. I think people don't like this question because see my other comment, but I fail to see how it's off topic or too broad. Yes would be nice if you clarified if you mean via magic or some device, but I think this one is kind of obvious

Answer (score 3):

## From "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy"

> There is an art to flying, or rather a knack. The knack lies
>    in learning how to throw yourself at the ground
>   and miss. ... Clearly, it is this second part, the missing,
>   that presents the difficulties.

Astronauts do this all the time.  They move so fast horizontally that they miss the earth.  Since the earth is round, they do this near indefinitely.

We call that act: `orbiting`.

Comment: But that's orbiting, not flying. If the superheroes want to fly, they can't orbit because they are inside the atmosphere, which will slow them down or rip them to shreds. How do they get to space in the first place?

Comment: The indestructible skin allows for in-atmosphere orbiting.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of sources for this. If all you want is sources, just do a Google search for "can humans fly".

[Here](https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/can-humans-fly-like-birds/) is one source from an MIT article. The problem is twofold. Human arms aren't strong enough to flap, and wings need a long length while also being light. The solution is a fixed-wing aircraft. The first such aircraft was flown by the Wright brothers. A fixed wing allows the person to pedal with their feet instead of their arms, and because they wings don't need to be flapped, they can be long and sturdy.

So if you want humans to be able to fly, the best solution is to use a fixed wing aircraft, also known as an airplane.

There is a Greek myth about Daedalus and Icarus, who fly over the ocean with wings made of feathers and wax. This is not possible in real life for the reasons in the paragraph above. However, if you give your superheroes super arm strength while not increasing their total weight, they would be able to fly with similar wings. The wings will be large and bulky, so you should make them removable.